# How to call a javascript function from Kotlin that expects a jQuery ajax settings object?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I need to convert the following code, it uses something in jQuery called an [ajax settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (which is used in the javascript below inside the `create()` call to create a [CouchDB database](https://couchdb.apache.org/))

```
$.couch.db("mydb").create({
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(status) {
        console.log(status);
    }
});
```

I have defined these

```
@JsName("$")
external val jq: JQuery

val jCouch: dynamic get() = jq.asDynamic().couch
```

but I am stuck on how to convert the javascript code

`jCouch.db.create("mydb")`.*what now*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways. First, you can create a `dynamic` object and set required properties there:

```
val settings: dynamic = Any()
settings.success = { data: dynamic -> console.log(data) }
settings.error = { status: dynamic -> console.log(status) }
jCouch.db("db").create(settings)
```

(you may also specify corresponding type for data or status)

Second, you can use `json` function:

```
jCouch.db("db").create(json(
    "success" to { ... }, // edit note: added missing comma
    "error" to { ... }
))
```

Third, you can write typed headers. I don't know what is Couch API, so headers would look *approximately* like that:

```
external interface Db {
    fun create(settings: DbCreateSettings)
}

external interface DbResult

external interface DbError

external interface DbCreateSettings {
    val success: ((DbResult) -> Unit)?
    val error: ((DbError) -> Unit)?
}

fun JQuery.db(name: String): Db = asDynamic().db(name)

fun foo() {
    jq.db("name").create(object : DbCreateSettings {
        override val success = { it: DbResult -> console.log(it) }
        override val error = { it: DbError -> console.log(it) }
    })
}
```

Finally, you can see how [Kotlin stdlib](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/4497874f314a5f2176df3bdaf0451eb398e255ac/js/js.libraries/src/generated/org.w3c.fetch.kt#L74) declares headers for options